# Requested Facebook permissions not taking effect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my app's extended permissions are not working, everytime I try to post to wall, I get this error `(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`, even though I have added in the right permissions, here is my code,

PHP:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1234456789',
  'secret' => 'secret'
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
        'next'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/'
    ));

} else {

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/', 
        'req_perms'=>'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos',
        'cancel_url' =>'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/'
    ));

    echo "<script>top.window.location='".$loginUrl."';</script>";

}
```

any idea why the permissions are not being set? Or why this is happening?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I could not understand your requirement. Do you want to use this in your web site or facebook itself. I see the URLs are facebook links not your domains.

Comment: Facebook itself, apologies if I was unclear about that.

Comment: What request are you trying to make that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific code that fails it's hard to help you.  But... according to FB's privacy settings, a user can choose which details to make available to applications:

**From facebook:**

*Choose Your Privacy Settings>Apps, Games and Websites>*
"Control what information is available to apps and websites when your friends use them."

It's possible that some user's have denied specific permissions and that's why it's returning an error.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/ to check granted permissions by uid.

But do show us the code :)